# nftables: "ipsec in reqid" raises "Can't process rule error"

Tags: raspberry-pi3, nftables

I'm trying to add an IPSec-related rule to my router:

```
# nft add rule inet t_fw c_in 'ip saddr 192.168.10.17 ipsec in reqid 1 accept'
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
add rule inet t_fw c_in ip saddr 192.168.10.17 ipsec in reqid 1 accept
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The system is a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 11, Kernel 5.15.23-v7. nftables, libmnl and libnftnl have been compiled manually today with sources from current Git master. nftables version is "nftables v1.0.2 (Lester Gooch)".

I did the same compile job (from the same sources) on a x86 test system (running Debian 11 with the default kernel), and I could add this rule without any problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone runs into the same problem: I recompiled the Raspbian kernel, and enabled all XFRM and nftables-realted options, some of which used to be disabled beforehand. The rule is working fine now.